# I'm losing context of `this` in the Backbone View

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, this

I'm trying to upgrade my typeahead with debounce functionality and so far I have had success only with the following code. It does debounce request, but when I define function as `something = func (args) ->` it does not get attached to the View instance and I can't access View's collection through `@collection`. However every other method defined like `something: ->` can be found on the View instance. Why is this happens? Thanks.

```
class productsView extends Marionette.CompositeView

    onDomRefresh: (options) ->
        @initTypeahead()

    initTypeahead: ->
        console.log @
        # outputs: productsView{...}
        @ui.typeahead_input.typeahead {
            hint: true
            highlight: true
            minLength: 1
        },
            source: (q, sync, async) => 
                requestDebouncer q, sync, async 

    requestDebouncer = _.debounce (q, sync, async) =>
        console.log @
        # outputs: function productsView()...
        console.log "debounced" 
    , 300
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it happened because you declared requestDebouncer in function productsView(). 
Try to make requestDebouncer as a instance method

```
requestDebouncer: -> _.debounce (q, sync, async) =>
    console.log @
    console.log "debounced" 
, 300
```

And call it as @requestDebouncer

P.s. I had never used coffeescript, only guess how its work.